# Exporting files from CVS according to file extension

Tags: batch-file, cvs

I'm using an executable batch file, to export files and folders from `CVS`. The commands are similar to the following:

```
cvs -d %cvs% -z9 -q export -r HEAD %path%/folder
```

Where %cvs% provides the data to access the `CVS` repository and %path% shows the path, from which the files are exported.

But as there are many files to export, then it takes up a lot of time. So I was wondering whether it is possible to specify that only files ending with .java extension would be exported?

If it is, how could I specify these requirements?

Answer (score 1):

**I think the answer is "no", you cannot use for example *.java wildcard on cvs.**

The only way to do it I think is about scripting, you can generate an script that makes cvs checkout only for the files you want, just making like:

```
for i in $ (cvs list yourRepo) do
    if (some condition to check if is .java file) echo "cvs -d %cvs% -z9 -q export -r HEAD %path%/folder/$i" >> myCheckoutScript.sh
done
```

And then execute that script that you generated, I have not a lot of time to answer, probably I will edit to a better script when I arrive home.